# Is there a way to exit a while loop by reading an empty line with nextLine()? (Java)

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

For an assignment I need to use a scanner to read an unspecified amount of inputs, and have a corresponding output as a response. In order to keep taking inputs I used the while loop:

```
while (!(readLine = scanner.nextLine()).equals(""))
```

The final entry ends with a "next line" so the scanner should be reading nothing, but the loop doesn't end until I press the enter key manually. Any insight on the cause?

Note: An example of the input that's going in is as follows

```
name specific_string1 specific_string2
command1 name specific_string2
command2 name
command3 name
```

I take out the first word from the string in order to use the command in a switch statement contained inside the loop, while the name and specific_strings are stored in variables. The nextLine() reads these line-by-line, but won't exit on its own.

Answer (score 0):

> The final entry ends with a "next line" so the scanner should be reading nothing, but the loop doesn't end until I press the enter key manually.

That is expected behavior.  The way that the operating system (and Java) knows that you have finished entering characters in a line is when you press ENTER.   Unless / until you type ENTER, you could type other characters .... making the line non-empty.  The ENTER key says "I, the user, have finished this line".

---

For the record, `scanner.nextLine()` can return `null`, so

```
    (readLine = scanner.nextLine()).equals("")
```

could throw an NPE.  When does the `nextLine()` return `null`?  When the `Scanner` reaches the end of stream.  How do you signal end-of-stream from a console?  By typing ^D (on Linux / MacOS) or ^Z (on Windows).

There may be an answer to your conundrum in the above ...

Comment: A note on that last part, would "while (!(readLine = scanner.nextLine()).isEmpty())" work better?

Comment: Nope.  Calling `null.isEmpty()` throws an NPE too.   Calling **any** instance method on `null` throws an NPE.